# Verify that a task switcher is correctly switching between tasks

Tags: assembly, mips

My MIPS Assembly teacher had us implement a task switcher that switches between two arbitrary tasks by saving and loading all the registers onto the stack. He asked us in class how we would test that our switcher was working correctly.

He hinted that it could be done with a single line of code, and that it could be done without knowing what the tasks are doing (ie, giving us the binaries)

Nobody in the class could figure out how he wanted us to do it, and he wouldn't tell us, he was just mad that we couldn't figure out this supposedly obvious thing.

So how are we supposed to do this?

Comment: hard to say without looking at the switcher code, but it sounds like quite a bogus claim. To thoroughly test it you would rather need hefty set of tests. Anyway, one idea how to make sure the stack store/restore works correctly is set up the initial environment of each task with recognizable bit patterns (i.e. each register has different value), and after the switch is prepared, just ahead of jumping into the task, jump to task-switch again. So the switcher will just keep switching the two environments without executing single instruction of task. If no value deviates, switching works (cough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was:

Run one task at a time, and check if the results are the same as when running multitask.

The single line of additional code that would allow this to work was `jr $ra` in the taskswitch routine to prevent it from actually switching